# Using CXF With an WSDL that has unpublished metadata

Tags: java, wcf, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm using CXF to to communicate with a WSDL made in WCF.  The WCF side of things was created following a [tutorial](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/search/label/Web%20Services%20Interoperability).  The Java code has been generated using a Maven script.

I have gotten things working using HTTPS for encryption.  I have gotten authentication working.  However, I would like to have the WSDL metadata turned off on the WCF side and still be able to use the Java side to talk to the service.

Currently, I can access the service with metadata publishing on from the Java side using this code:

```
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("https://server.com:7010/Hservice?wsdl");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) wsdlLocation.openConnection();
HService service = new HService(wsdlLocation);
HAdminService calc = service.getHAdminService();
... (authentication using WSS4JOutInterceptor code and unrelated code here)
System.out.println(calc.add(new Double(5), new Double(5)));
```

However, when I turn off metadata publishing on the WCF side I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.blah.hservice.v_1_0.HService.<init>(HService.java:49)
    at Main.main(Main.java:85)`
```

The page the wsdl is on displays this with metadata publishing turned off (this is an excerpt):

```
This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.

 Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:
```

I expected to be able to search "CXF metadata unpublished" and see lots of people doing this...but have not found anything.  How do I communicate with this service without the WSDL being published?

Answer (score 2):

You really have two options:

1. Copy the wsdl locally and point the client at the local wsdl.   This is likely the "best" option as it makes sure all the information in the wsdl (like policies and such) is used.
2. Use "null" for the wsdl location (note: not JAX-WS portable).   You will need to call service.addPort(....) after creating the service and before calling getHAdminService to add the port with the appropriate binding and endpoint address.   CXF can work most of the time without the WSDL (will internally generate what is needed from the annotations).   However, if things like policies are defined in the WSDL, then it cannot.

Comment: So now I have `service.addPort(HService.HAdminService, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/", "https://something.com:7010/hservice?wsdl");`

And I get a null pointer on

`HAdminService calc = service.getHAdminService();`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with Client code I generated using CXF 2.6.5

Make sure the QName(first argument) matches the QName the getHAdminService() method references. The bindingId(second argument) should be one of the constants defined in SOAPBinding Interface (javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding).